# All navigation in a single page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am new in Windows 8 apps using XAML and C#.
I want  all navigation in a single page and I have created a button in main page and then create a second page.  When user click on button from main page it 2nd page must show in main page.
How can I do this?

Main page xaml :

```
<Button Content="click" FontSize="60" Margin="191,283,0,382" Height="103" 
Click="Button_Click" ></Button>
```

Main page:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1),"p");
}
```

page 1:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="59" SelectionChanged="TextBlock_SelectionChanged">
    hi  2nd page is open
</TextBlock>
```

When user clicks on button the second page should be shown in main page.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Frame` inside your main page. Try this

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="227*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1139*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Name="firstPageButton" Content="First Page" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="53" Width="227" Click="firstPageButton_Click"/>

    <Frame Name="rootFrame" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Height="758" Width="1129"/>

</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private void firstPageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1),"p");    
}
```

**Note**:
         When ever you add page in `metro apps`, just keep in mind that you always add `Split Page` from Visual Studio Template instead of `Blank Page` because `Split Page` contains some default built in functionality like `Title`, `Back Button`,`GoBack()` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot Muhammad Umar .ALLAH bless u always :)

Comment: You are welocome. If my answer help you then mark it as an answer.